# Finding the cause of Style problems

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, xaml, styles

In a large WPF-project setting padding on buttons does not have any effect what so ever. No styles, templates, etc are set on the button, but still it won't use my padding.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Padding="20, 20">Hello</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

I tried this in a brand new project and it works like a charm. Obviously there is some global style, template somewhere in the project causing this. Either somewhere in the xaml file, or in some resource file. As this project is rather hefty I going through *everything* is not feasable.

How to I debug this? Can I see what is overriding the padding?

I tried snooping around with [Snoop 2.7.0](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), but it didn't really tell me much. Any hints on how to proceed with this type of error?

### EDIT

I loked at the [ValueSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper.getvaluesource.aspx) for some properties:

- Padding=Local
- ContentTemplate=Default
- Template=Style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular problem was caused by a style defined in a resource included in the `App.xaml`.

The important lesson here is that styles without the `x:Key` attribute will affect *all* elements of the target type as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx#styling_basics).

Performing a solution wide wild card search on `<Style*TargetType="*Button` yielded a list of potential styles that would affect my button. I found one *without* the `x:Key` attribute, commented it out just to try and *voila*! The padding works.

Answer (score 1):

What about the method DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper.getvaluesource.aspx

Comment: Here is an example

http://wpf.2000things.com/2010/12/05/146-use-getvaluesource-method-to-find-the-source-of-a-dependency-property-value/

Comment: yeah, found that too. :) Thanks

Comment: I suggest also considering the Dependency Property Value Precedence

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a page on [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) in the MSDN.

Why is it important? few people really know the order of precedence when it comes to dependency property values.

For example, did you know that whatever value you set in the CoerceValueCallback of a DP will overwrite any other set?

I'd suggest you go over that link and start from top (strongest set, will overwrite anything) to bottom (weakest set, will get overwritten by anything), there's a level in there where your value got set.

But hey, if you look at that list, you'll notice you're already in position 3! *local value*. So you only have 2 levels up: animation and value coercion ;)

Answer (score 1):

I find your own answer might not be correct as well.

Whatever you put in your Button object will overwrite what's defined in the style.

I guess the reason that the padding you defined inside the button doesn't do anything is because, in your default style, the ContentPresenter is missing this,

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
```

The padding is the distance between the text and the border of the button, that is, the margin of this ContentPresenter.

Comment: nice catch! This was actually missing from the ContentPresenter, but putting the Margin in there did not help, the actual textblock moved around but the size of the button was not affected...

Comment: the size of the button doesn't change based on the padding of its content, if the button is not small and you assign a large padding to it, the text will simply not show.

Comment: yeah, exactly. But if I use the default style the size of the button will change too.

Comment: that's because you are setting the width and height of the button to auto right? can you post the xaml code of your button style?

Comment: nah, wont bother with posting it. There is pretty much of stuff in there. The width is not set from what I can tell though, but the height is set in the style. Neither changes with the padding though...

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock Padding="20" Text="Hello world!" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: If you read the question it works for me too in a new project.